# Как найти View находящийся в LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Имеется обычный `TextView` который находится внутри `LinearLayout`(гор) который в свою очередь находится внутри `LinearLayout`(верт). Я хочу повесить слушатель на него.
Когда я запускаю приложение оно крашится с ошибкой

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Никак не могу понять в чем проблема, `TextView` определен

```
text = findViewById(R.id.Text);
```

Пытался найти в интернете инфу но смог понять только то, что проблема из-за нахождения `TextView` внутри `LinearLayout`, а значит нужно определеять вьюху как то по другому

разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/simpleGray">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fuelDateText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="ДАТА"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/FuelSetDate"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/FuelSetDate" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_button_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addFuel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/alpha_0"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clarify" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

сам код

```
    package com.EViCo.revivemycar.additionals;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.EViCo.revivemycar.R;
import com.EViCo.revivemycar.DataBase;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Add_fuel extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private TextView datetext;
    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_2);

        LinearLayout l = findViewById(R.id.l);
        LinearLayout l1 = l.findViewById(R.id.date_row);
        LinearLayout l5 = l.findViewById(R.id.add_button_row);


        datetext = l1.findViewById(R.id.FuelDateText);
        datetext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                set_new_date();
            }
        });

        Button add = l5.findViewById(R.id.AddFuel);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

            }
        });
        setInitialDateTime();
    }

    // установка начальных даты и времени
    private void setInitialDateTime()
    {
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        datetext.setText(date);
    }

    private void set_new_date()
    {
        new DatePickerDialog(Add_fuel.this, datepicker,
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                .show();
    }

    private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datepicker  = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            setInitialDateTime();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В разметке написано:

```
android:id="@+id/fuelDateText"
```

В коде написано:

```
datetext = l1.findViewById(R.id.FuelDateText);
```

Проблема заключается в том, не совпадают регистры символов, поэтому `fuelDateText` и `FuelDateText` воспринимаются за разные вещи. Можно вместо этой строки кода подставить это:

```
datetext = l1.findViewById(R.id.fuelDateText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант:

1. Находим сам `LinearLayout`:

   `LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.linear)`
2. Находим вьюху в самом `LinearLayout`:

   `View view = ll.findViewById(R.id.view)`

Comment: к сожалению ошибка осталась

Answer (score 1):

У вас в разметке `TextView` имеет id `android:id="@+id/fuelDateText"`, но в коде вы его дергаете как `datetext = l1.findViewById(R.id.FuelDateText);`. Придерживайтесь явовской [стилистики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).